# How to loop same functionality for each table row?

Tags: javascript

I want to calculate total price based on cargo price. It works for the first row. But if there have multiple rows it doesn't work . How can I loop same functionality for each row  on table? can someone please help me ?

```js
   function calcCargo(){
            var price = parseFloat(document.querySelector('.price').value);
            var total = document.querySelector('.total');
            var cargo = document.querySelector(".cargo");
            var totalCargoAndPrice = price + parseFloat(cargo.value);
            total.value = totalCargoAndPrice;
            console.log(totalCargoAndPrice);    
        }
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <table class="table" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="font-weight-bold text-success">Price</th>
        <th class="font-weight-bold text-success">Quantity</th>
        <th class="font-weight-bold text-success">Cargo Price</th>
        <th class="font-weight-bold text-success">Total</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="products">
      <tr>

        <td>
          <input type="number" class="form-control price" value="15" name="price[]" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="number" class="form-control" value="1" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="number" class="form-control cargo" value="0" onchange="calcCargo()" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="number" class="form-control total" disabled="disabled" id="t-{{ $item->id }}" placeholder="0" />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>

        <td>
          <input type="number" class="form-control price" value="15" name="price[]" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="number" class="form-control" value="1" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="number" class="form-control cargo" value="0" onchange="calcCargo()" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="number" class="form-control total" disabled="disabled" id="t-{{ $item->id }}" placeholder="0" />
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this:

```js
function calcCargo(e) {
  var row = e.target.parentElement.parentElement;
  var price = parseFloat(row.querySelector('.price').value);
  var total = row.querySelector('.total');
  var cargo = row.querySelector(".cargo");
  var totalCargoAndPrice = price + parseFloat(cargo.value);
  total.value = totalCargoAndPrice;
  console.log(totalCargoAndPrice);
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <table class="table" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="font-weight-bold text-success">Price</th>
        <th class="font-weight-bold text-success">Quantity</th>
        <th class="font-weight-bold text-success">Cargo Price</th>
        <th class="font-weight-bold text-success">Total</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="products">
      <tr>

        <td>
          <input type="number" class="form-control price" value="15" name="price[]" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="number" class="form-control" value="1" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="number" class="form-control cargo" value="0" onchange="calcCargo(event)" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="number" class="form-control total" disabled="disabled" id="t-{{ $item->id }}" placeholder="0" />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>

        <td>
          <input type="number" class="form-control price" value="15" name="price[]" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="number" class="form-control" value="1" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="number" class="form-control cargo" value="0" onchange="calcCargo(event)" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="number" class="form-control total" disabled="disabled" id="t-{{ $item->id }}" placeholder="0" />
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

By passing an event object into the `calcCargo` function, you can identify which input element fired the event, so you can find that row and update only the fields inside it.

Comment: It helped and thanks for explanation also. It make sense.

Comment: I'm glad it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

This does not work because `document.querySelector(` gets you the first found element. (Explains why its working for the first row!).

### JS

```
function calcCargo(target){
  const row = target.closest("tr");
  var price = parseFloat(row.querySelector('.price').value);
  var total = row.querySelector('.total');
  var cargo = row.querySelector(".cargo");
  var totalCargoAndPrice = price + parseFloat(cargo.value);
  total.value = totalCargoAndPrice;
}
```

### HTML

```
<div class="row">
  <table class="table" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="font-weight-bold text-success">Price</th>
        <th class="font-weight-bold text-success">Quantity</th>
        <th class="font-weight-bold text-success">Cargo Price</th>
        <th class="font-weight-bold text-success">Total</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="products">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="number" class="form-control price" value="15" name="price[]" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="number" class="form-control" value="1" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="number" class="form-control cargo" value="0" onchange="calcCargo(this)" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="number" class="form-control total" disabled="disabled" id="t-{{ $item->id }}" placeholder="0" />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="number" class="form-control price" value="15" name="price[]" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="number" class="form-control" value="1" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="number" class="form-control cargo" value="0" onchange="calcCargo(this)" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="number" class="form-control total" disabled="disabled" id="t-{{ $item->id }}" placeholder="0" />
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: I have tried the querySelectorAll also. It did not help

Answer (score 0):

```
// You can do it multiple wasys, but here is one of them

// first you need to collect every table-cell that contains the vaklue you need to summarize.
const cargoItems = document.querySelectorAll('td .cargo')
// this is the way you get all values and now you need just iterate over this input nodes and get the values. And the most elegant way to do that - use Array.prototypre.reduce.call()

// it may looks quizzically, but html nodes collection has no personal reduce method, that can helps us to itertate over the data. Let's do it

// in this case every htmlNode becomes an rec - receiver, and variable that will accumulate all values is a 'acc'. 0 set as default value, that increments untill your cargo inputs ends
const summ = Array.prototypre.reduce.call(cargoItems, (acc, rec) => {
  return acc + parseFloat(rec.value)
}, 0)

// show result
console.log(summ)
```